# How to make a function that replaces some words with abbreviation?

Tags: python, dictionary

So I need to make a function that takes a string from the user and then using a global constant, change some words into abbreviation form. PLEASE becomes PLZ and etc. One other thing once the user enters the string it shouldn't ask the user if they want to replace the word, it should do it automatically.

```
replacements = {
'TOMORROW': 'TMR',
'ABOUT': 'BOUT',
'PLEASE': 'PLZ',
'BEFORE': 'B4',
}


def uppercase(newWord):
    new_uppercase=''
    for letters in newWord:
        if ord(letters) > 96:
            new_uppercase += chr(ord(letters)-32)
        else:
            new_uppercase += letters
    print(new_uppercase)
    return new_uppercase

def replace(newString):
    old,new = [],[]
    for ch in newString:
        if replacements.get(ch):
            newString = newString.replace(ch, replacements.get(ch))
        print(newString)

# this is the definition of your main function
def main():
    print("Hello, And Welcome to this Slang Program")
    cap_letters = input("Please enter your string here: ")  
    uppercase(cap_letters)
    # write the part of the program that interacts with the user here
    replace(uppercase(cap_letters))

# these should be the last two lines of your submission
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You can also try using `map`

Comment: wdym a map, im pretty new at coding

Comment: You should pay attention to your line that reads:
`for ch in newString:`
What you are doing there is looping over every character, **not every word** in the string. Fix that and you'll be good.

Comment: How would i change it to every word instead?

Comment: And I would suggest using list comprehensions inside most functions.. surely that is counted as from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're trying to implement a `replace` method from scratch? If not, Python already has a fantastic method for this. You can call `str.replace` on any string:

```py
replacements = {
  'TOMORROW': 'TMR',
  'ABOUT': 'BOUT',
  'PLEASE': 'PLZ',
  'BEFORE': 'B4',
};

test_string = "PLEASE meet me TOMORROW BEFORE noon"

# loop through all replacements
for find, replace in replacements.iteritems():
  # replace the "find" key with the "replace" value
  # e.g. replace "PLEASE" (find) with "PLZ" (replace)
  test_string = test_string.replace(find, replace)

print test_string
# output: PLZ meet me TMR B4 noon
```

Comment: i have to make one from scratch